# How to get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPassword distinguish name?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to get the `ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy` to a specific folder in the AD tree. `'OU=FOLDER,OU=FOLDER,DC=Domain,=DC=net'`

I would like to search for users who will expire within whatever amount of days I set to look for users accounts that will expire and create a report.

I've tried doing -server FQDN and -identity variances.

I've tried setting the SearchBase filter to the FQDN as well... I'm at a lost and I'm still green.

## *EDITED TO SHOW THAT IS NOW WORKING*

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
 
#Set the number of days within expiration.  This will start to send the email x number of days before it is expired.
$DaysWithinExpiration = 30
 
#Set the days where the password is already expired and needs to change. -- Do Not Modify --
$MaxPwdAge   = (Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy -Identity spihost.net).MaxPasswordAge.Days
$expiredDate = (Get-Date).addDays(-$MaxPwdAge)
 
#Set the number of days until you would like to begin notifing the users. -- Do Not Modify --
$passwordDate = (Get-Date).addDays(-($MaxPwdAge - $DaysWithinExpiration))
 
#Filters for all users who's password is within $date of expiration.
$ExpiredUsers = Get-ADUser -searchbase "OU=SUBFOLDER,OU=MAINFOLDER,DC=DOMAIN,DC=com" -Filter {(PasswordLastSet -lt $passwordDate) -and (PasswordLastSet -gt $expiredDate) -and (PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false) -and (Enabled -eq $true)} -Properties PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordLastSet, Mail | select samaccountname, PasswordLastSet, @{name = "DaysUntilExpired"; Expression = {$_.PasswordLastSet - $ExpiredDate | select -ExpandProperty Days}}, @{name = "password"; Expression = {$_.mail}} | Sort-Object PasswordLastSet
 
# Rename CHANGEME to sitecode 
$ExpiredUsers | Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\CHANGEME_30_days.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what you need to do.
AD default domain password policy is tied to the AD domain, not to OUs. To get more granularity (i.e. to apply a Policy to a single AD group) you need to use Fine Grained Password Policy (FGPP)
See here:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2013/05/29/step-by-step-enabling-and-using-fine-grained-password-policies-in-ad/

Comment: Hello Thanks for your reply. I ended up figuring out what the issue is.

I needed to add: 
Get-ADUser -searchbase "OU=SUBFOLDER,OU=MAINFOLDER,DC=DOMAIN,DC=com"

before my filter to grab the exact OU I wanted. Edited main post to results found.